# HTML fixed header is changing position when page is refreshed

Tags: css, html

I am working on this HTML code which has a fixed header. It works just fine until I refresh the page, it gets down to the current section. I tried many ways but could not figure out the problem. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```css
.subMenu {
 position:fixed;
 top:163px;
 height: 50px;
 z-index: 2000;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 1px solid #C7E603;
 background: url(../images/nav-bg.png) repeat-x #80B404;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #1F1E20;
}
.subMenu .inner {
 padding: 0;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.subNavBtn {
 display: block;
 height: 35px;
 width: 9.48%;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
 padding: 15px 2% 0 2%;
 text-align: center;
 color: #3C6B00;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 border-left: 2px ridge #8FDF00;
 background: url(../images/nav_li.png) 0 -100px repeat-x;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="subMenu">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="toolbar">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#sTop" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#s1" id="s1" class="subNavBtn">About</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#s2" id="s2" class="subNavBtn">Facilities</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#ss" id="ss" class="subNavBtn">Gallery</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#s3" id="s3" class="subNavBtn">Events</a> </li>
          <li>  <a href="#s4" id="s4" class="subNavBtn">Services</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="s5" id="s5" class="subNavBtn">Contact</a> </li>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify "gets down to the current section"?

Comment: It is a one page template so the header is going down the currently div/section whenever refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

ok u have to add line-hieght:50px;display:inline;
in .submenu

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your comment helpped much.
I've seen in your source code that you are using jQuery sMint for your sticky nav, which overrides your css property with inline generated property on your `.subMenu` class.

So it calculates the position from the top of the page + 163px (when it bugs).

I've seen that you have 2 `s2` classes. One for franchise page and one for facilities(staff) page. And once you reached facilities page and beyond the fixed navbar has the right behavior.

So my advice is to increment properly your sections classes and tel us back if the bug remains.

Comment: Please check this link "bumblebee.perfect12technologies.com". Refresh it after scrolling down and you will see the header changes its position.

Comment: I incremented the sections correctly. Still the same issue.

Comment: Actually it works fine with top: 0px but the thing is my header should be little above the slider. That is where it got messed up.

Comment: Did you try to wrap your 2 sections which had the same s2 class in one as there is no menu link for one of those ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the html and css that you provided. Please try the following:
increase the height of the `.subMenu` to `80px`
also give the following styles to `ul` - `overflow:hidden; list-style:none;`

Comment: That dint work. This link would be more helpful bumblebee.perfect12technologies.com